# Facebook messenger webhook did not receive any messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I am a beginner to use Facebook Graph API. I'm trying to set up a webhook to receive and send messages (or just only send messages). I have already verified it and succeeded. Then my webhook's also received messages from test webhooks. But when I use a real account to send messages or some acctions to my page. Nothing happened in my webhook.
Here's is my simple code in my webhook.

```
@csrf_exempt        
def WebhookPAGEAPI(request):
    event_json = json.loads(request.body)
    print(event_json)
    return HttpResponse('OK',status=200)
```

I tried enable live mode but still failed.

Comment: As long as your app is in “dev” mode, most stuff like this is only supposed to work for user accounts that have a role in the app. And it doesn’t magically start to work for everyone just because you flip the “live” switch - the use of most permissions and features your app uses, needs to be approved by Facebook in app review first.

Comment: OK. I got it.  Thanks for you help ^^.